# How to change the (permanent) MAC address on my android phone?

Tags: mac-address

In the past months, I've got 2 Chinese Android cells (Froyo) based on MTK6515. They work fine but we started having lot of trouble attempting access to internet, and after a while I found out that both phones they have the same MAC address, which causes connection problems. So, I'm looking for a procedure that could change the devices' MAC addresses and solve our trouble.

I found a method which involves changing the file at `/etc/wl/NVRAM.TXT`, but after referencing a couple posts around the webs, it turns out my phones do not have this folder (and thus the other files inside). Any clue?

Please don't tell me a pray about that MAC addresses are burned into a chip, at least not in these devices, because I've already lost their IMEI's too (by hard reset), but I've recovered them and they're functional now.

Comment: Maybe you can change the MAC Address via `ifconfig`. See this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9649/change-mac-address-android-using-ip-link

Comment: You can't actually change the mac address, only spoof it, because a mac address is coded into the hardware

Answer (score 9):

I found [a tutorial on MAC address spoofing at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1385577) that might be helpful:

> REQUIREMENTS
>
> 1) ROOTED PHONE 2) BUSYBOX INSTALLED 3) Terminal App
>
> OPEN UP TERMINAL AND WRITE
>
> :su :busybox iplink show eth0
>
> (THIS WILL SHOW YOUR CURRENT MAC ADDRESS)
>
> NOW TYPE IN
>
> :busybox ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
>
> (INSTEAD OF 00:11:22:33:44:55, YOU CAN WRITE YOUR WANTED ADDRESS)
>
> CONGRATULATION, YOU HAVE SUCCESSFULLY SPOOFED YOUR MAC ADDRESS!
>
> YOU CAN CHECK YOUR MAC ADDRESS BY TYPING
>
> :busybox iplink show eth0

I don't think this is permanent however.  I did find [another guide on Android Forums that seems to be permanent](http://androidforums.com/t-mobile-g1/3506-changing-spoofing-mac-address.html):

> After your rooted head into terminal emulation type su and go into
>   /data/misc/wifi
>
> Look for a file called nvram.txt
>
> Copy it to your sdcard and then to your cpu desktop open it with
>   notepad and at the bottom of nvram.txt is the mac address
>
> This i was able to verify and test on android Citrus Ciena
>
> Edit that mac address and save it as nvram1.txt onto sdcard
>
> Now go back to data wifi misc and copy nvram.txt to nvram.bak
>
> Head into gui and then settings then wifi then turn on the wifi but
>   don't connect to any wifi
>
> turn off the wifi,switch back to terminal
>
> Copy the nvram1.txt to data misc wifi
>
> remove the original (make sure you got it backed up)
>
> Rename nvram1.txt to nvram.txt
>
> head back into gui and then settings then wifi
>
> Now for me it immediately stated unable to turn on wifi
>
> Ignore it and try to turn it on anyways
>
> When it turns on your newly edited mac address will take effect
>
> Connect to your AP
>
> NOW B4 REBOOTING YOU MUST CHANGE NVRAM BACK TO THE ORIGINAL!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I have a phone based on MTK6515 dualsim and NVRAM.TXT is not present, nor /etc/wl so, i found similar posts before in other forums and i attempted to apply with no successful. I read too, there are a lot phones with same wifi and BT MAC ADDRESS. Wow, it becames a big trouble using two or more phones in a same wifi network (like happend to me). This is the waybecause i ask for a permanent change of MAC. Any idea about how to fix this trouble?.

Comment: Have you tried *creating* said files and folders and seeing if it works?

Comment: How can I write this configuration? I have no idea what I have to integrate in this file to spoof the mac address in this phone. I think the device is capable of changing its MAC permanently. Any idea about where I download this file to modify it? Thanks a lot.