# Hide my device type when connected to Wi-Fi

Tags: root-access

I have seen that many scanning tools and commands show that my device is a Samsung.

Is there any way to mask my device type into a different device or into **Unknown**?. My Galaxy S5 mini is rooted as well.

Comment: They're probably identifying the manufacturer from the MAC address of your device. [How to change the (permanent) MAC address on my android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17657/how-to-change-the-permanent-mac-address-on-my-android-phone) and [Change MAC address Android using ip link?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9649/change-mac-address-android-using-ip-link) might be helpful.

Comment: @Huey I have Pry-Fi to change MAC address. I can search a list of manufacturer's MAC address range and change it. Trying now and scanning to see if that works

Comment: @Huey I changed wlan0 mac to an apple one. Still says Samsung phone... Could actually be because my phone itself did the scan, but are there any other identifiers that scanners would use to determine if it's a Samsung phone, or an Apple MacBook?

Comment: It could do a port scan to identify what open ports there are and the kind of services running. I'm not an expert, but Android phones probably have specific ports open for services like [GCM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571576/which-port-and-protocol-does-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-use) that can strongly suggest a particular device runs Android. Manufacturer-specific services such as Kies can also identify a Samsung phone for instance.

Comment: Any update on this?